# How to get HTTP form data from POST payload in Java HttpServlet?

Tags: java, servlets, http-post

I try to extract the form data from an `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` instance. As recommended online I tried `request.getParameter(String paramKey)`, but it did not work. `request.getParameterValues()`, `request.getParameterNames()` and `request.getParameterMap()` return no form data as well. What I want is a Map with form data or another method to get them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it will behave where you write the code request.getParameter().
this thing always needs to write in the doGetPost() Method of the servlet like mentioned below. refer the following example.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException  {

     String id = req.getParameter("realname");
     String password = req.getParameter("mypassword");
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id = req.getParameter("realname");
    String password = req.getParameter("mypassword");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to configure.

1. need to set `"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` for the request
2. need to set `@MultipartConfig` annotation for the class
3. get Part from `request.getPart("KEY")`;
4. read the Stream

here is my example

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet("/")
@MultipartConfig
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5589752892736045780L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        //get part by key
        Part part = req.getPart("override");
        
        //read the part
        InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        
        //set it to the response
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the Postman request
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you need to override. They are `doPost(), doGet(), service()`

`doPost()` will get executed when the received request type is **POST**.

`doGet()` will get executed when the received request type is **GET**.

If you want a single method which should be executed for the both post, get you better to use `service()` method.

**Example:**

```
 public class TestServlet{

    public void service( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ){

        request.getParameter( "paramterName" ).
    }
 }
```